# Why child process pipe is showing in parent process with different pipe details

Tags: c, linux

I am learning c program fork and pipe. I create a fork shown below.

**parent=> child1=>child2**

In parent we are creating a pipe.And the file descriptor are stored in parentpip.

In Child1 also i am creating a pipe. And the file descriptor are stored in child1pip.

Now when i check the process id  fd in /proc//fd. Below things are getting displayed.

If i do **ls -l /proc/15585/fd**  .. This is for parent

```
lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 1 -> /dev/pts/1 
lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 2 -> /dev/pts/1 
lr-x------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 3 -> 'pipe:[354240]' 
l-wx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 4 -> 'pipe:[354240]' 
lr-x------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 5 -> 'pipe:[354241]' 
l-wx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 6 -> 'pipe:[354241]'
```

If i do **ls -l /proc/15586/fd**  .. This is for child1

```
 lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 1 -> /dev/pts/1
 lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 3 -> 'pipe:[354240]'
l-wx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 4 -> 'pipe:[354240]'
lr-x------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 5 -> 'pipe:[357693]'
l-wx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 6 -> 'pipe:[357693]'
```

If i do **ls -l /proc/15587/fd**  .. This is for child2

```
lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 3 -> 'pipe:[354240]'
l-wx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 4 -> 'pipe:[354240]'
lr-x------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 5 -> 'pipe:[357693]'
l-wx------ 1 vipin vipin 64 Jan 14 17:33 6 -> 'pipe:[357693]'
```

Here filedescriptor 3 and 4 is belong to parentpip. So same pipe among all the process **pipe:[354240]** and **pipe:[354240]**

When we see filedescriptor 5 and 6 child2 and child1 hold the same child1pip. **pipe:[357693]** and **pipe:[357693]**

But i can see 5 and 6 in parent also Why also in parent. And the pip is  **pipe:[354241]** and **pipe:[354241]**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{

    int parentpip[2];

    pipe(parentpip);

    int child1pid =fork();

    int child1pip[2];
    pipe(child1pip);

    if(child1pid==0)
    {
        printf("This child1");
        int child2pid2=fork();
        if(child2pid2==0)
        {
          printf("This child2");
        }
        sleep(20*60);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This parent");
        sleep(20*60) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both the parent and child1 run `pipe(child1pip); `. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes. Parent is holding pipe pipe:[354241]  But child1 and child2 is holding pipe:[357693]. Why?

Comment: Because the parent called `pipe` after the `fork`, so both child1 and parent called `pipe` and you created 2 pipes (3 total)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I did not understand.  Why three. Parent is created a pipe. It is 'pipe:[354240]. And child1 also created a pipe pipe:[357693]. Then why parent is creating pipe:[354241]. The pipe pipe:[354241] is share among which process?

Comment: The parent creates 2 pipes.  Because it calls `pipe` twice. The child creates 1 pipe.  So the total is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these things happening.

1. parent creates pipe 354240 stored in parentpip
2. child1 is forked from parent, inheriting pipe 354240
3. parent creates pipe 354241 stored in child1pip
4. child1 creates pipe 357693 stored in child1pip
5. child2 is forked from child1, inheriting pipe 354240  and 357693

Note in point 3, the parent also runs the line of code: `pipe(child1pip);`
creating a new pipe - and so does the child1 process - both these processes creates their own pipes since this happens after fork().

You probably only need child1 to run `pipe(child1pip);` so change this code:

```
int child1pip[2];
pipe(child1pip);

if(child1pid==0)
{
```

To this code:

```
if(child1pid==0)
{
     int child1pip[2];
     pipe(child1pip
```

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. What is the use of 354241? It is not inherited anywhere... Can any of the child process talk through that pipe?

Comment: There's no use for it so far in this code, none of the child processes can use it. You should perhaps create that pipe inside the `if(child1pid==0)` branch.

Comment: Can you please update your suggestion code in the answer with complete source code. It will be very helpful  to understand.